# WPF Send value from TextBlock into method

Tags: c#, wpf

Main window.xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SummonerNameDTO}"/>
<Button Click="Button_Click">Find</Button>
```

Button_Click

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var SummonerName = _summonerDTOService.GetSummonerDTO(_viewModel.SummonerNameDTO).Id;
}
```

SummonerDTOResponse GetSummonerDTO()

```
public class SummonerDTOService
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/");
    public SummonerDTOResponse GetSummonerDTO(string SummonerName)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("by-name/{summonerName}")
            .AddParameter("summonerName", SummonerName, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
            .AddParameter("api_key", "api-key");
        var response = client.Execute<SummonerDTOResponse>(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return default;
        }
        return response.Data;
    }
}
public class SummonerDTOResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

}

I want to send from TextBlock value into summonerDTOResponse GetSummonerDTO().

Comment: Since you seem to be having a view model, you should of course pass the value of the view model's `SummonerNameDTO` property - to which the TextBox is bound - instead of the Text of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a name to the TextBlock

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSummonerNameDTO" Text="{Binding SummonerNameDTO}"/>
```

and use the TextBlock value to pass

```
var summonerDTO = _summonerDTOService.GetSummonerDTO(txtSummonerNameDTO.Text);
```

---

Since the TextBox's Text property is bound to a `SummonerNameDTO` property in a view model, you would usually access the view model instead of the UI:

```
var summonerDTO = _summonerDTOService.GetSummonerDTO(
    ((YourViewModel)DataContext).SummonerNameDTO);
```

Comment: @Clemens
[Code](https://i.imgur.com/zd3LIN6.png).
It's what I did still geting null :/

Comment: @d0natxd Maybe the TextBox hasn't yet lost focus, Try `Text="{Binding SummonerNameDTO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.